# highlight a secondary y-axis with dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs

I have a dygraph graph and I want a way of identify the axis a serie refers to.

I tried the following highlight method, but any suggestion to display clearly the y-axis is welcome

When I hover, I use the highlight feature on the serie, but I'd also want to highlight the y-axis. I have tried the highlight callback, but I enter in the following issue

```
highlightCallback: function(event, x, points, row, seriesName) {
        var hiProps = {
            axisLineColor: 'cyan',
            axisLineWidth: 10
        };
        var unhiProps = {
            axisLineColor: 'white',
            axisLineWidth: 0.3
        };
        var opts={axes: {
            y: unhiProps,
            y2: unhiProps
        }};
        var p=that.getParam(seriesName);
        if (p.y2) {
            opts.axes.y2 = hiProps; 
        } else {
            opts.axes.y = hiProps; 
        }
        that.graph.updateOptions(opts);
    },
```

My issue is that by calling `updateOptions`, the graph recomputes and the legend is reinitialized. I loose the values display

Answer (score 0):

dygraphs clears the selection when you call `updateOptions`. You can work around this by calling [`getSelection`](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#getSelection) before calling `updateOptions` and then calling [`setSelection`](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#setSelection) afterwards.